# Quick question about inequality

Tags: inequality

When i have :

$$a\leq b \lt d \leq c$$

Then, which one is true?

1. $a\lt c$
2. $a\leq c$
3. All wrong.
4. Both are right

Please state why.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you see any contradiction when $a = c$?

Comment: If $a=c$, then $a\leq b<d\leq a$, which implies that $a=b=c=d$, which contradicts $b<d$.

Comment: Thanks before. And what if i have $x\leq y \lt z$ what does this imply?

Comment: @DonThousand But $a<c \implies a\le c$.

Comment: @Gregory $a=c$ is in contradiction with $a<c$ but $a \le c$ is not.

Comment: Here's an alternative question.  $x = 36$ which is true  1) $x$ is an even number.  2) $x$ is a perfect square  3) $x$ is a square of an even number.  4) they are all wrong.  1),2), 3) are all correct  but 3) is the strongest one.  $a \le c$ is correct.  And $a < c$ is correct.  They both are.  But $a < c$ is  a stronger statement..  But $a\le c$ is true if $a < c$.  Just as $\alpha \le \beta$ is true if $\alpha = \beta$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You left out 4) Both are right.

1) is correct.  $a \le c$.

2) is correct.  $a < c$

3) is false.  Both 1 and 2  are *RIGHT*.

I think what is confusing you is that $a \le c$ is *not* incorrect when $a < c$.

$a \le c$ means $a = c$ OR $a < c$ and the OR statement is true when one or the other or both of them are true.  It is *not* false if you know one of them is definitely false but the other is true.

Even if you *KNOW* $a \ne c$ it is *still* true that $a=c$ OR $a < c$.

That's how OR statements work. We *use* them we don't know which is true.  But if we *do* find out one of them is false, that doesn't mean suddenly the statement is false.

Consider the follow:

$5 < 7$.  That is true.

$5 = 7$.  That is false.

$5 \le 7$.  That is true.

$5 > 7$.  That is false.

and consider the following:

$5 < 5$.  That is false.

$5 = 5$.  That is true.

$5 \le 5$.  That is true.

$5 > 5$.  That is false.

......

Any who.... inequalities are transitive.

$a \le b$ and $b < d$ meand $a < d$.

And $d < c$ and $a < d$ so $a < c$.

So $a \le c$.

If $M < N$ then $M \le N$ is *ALSO* true.

The only way $M \le N$ is *false* is if $M > N$.

Comment: Ok thanks. It's clear for me. :)

Answer (score 1):

We have that since

$$a\leq b \lt d \leq c $$

$a<c$ is true and also $a\le c$ is true since

$$a\le c \iff a=c \quad \lor \quad a<c$$

Comment: I'm thinking about $p\Rightarrow q$. When p is *false* then $p\Rightarrow q$ is always true. And in that case $a=c$ is false statement as Don Thousand said, which is contradicts with $b<d$. Is there a relationship??

Comment: @user516076 The key point is the defintion of $\le$ that is $$a\le c \iff a=c \quad \lor \quad a<c$$ therefore both are true,

Comment: Ok. Last 2 questions. Thanks before. And what if i have 1) $x\leq y \lt z$ and 2) $x\lt y \leq z$ what does this imply? Are those equivalent, if it isn't what are those implication be? And why?

Comment: @user516076 They are not equivalent of course. For example $5\le 5<6$ is true but $5<5\le 6$ is false.